# Why am I not populating my arrayList from CSV file with this class

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, filereader

I want to fill an arrayList using a class to condense my main method. So, I'd like to populate my arrayList using a "list" class, and then use it in my main to populate it. I'm not sure what part I'm missing, but this is what I have in the list class:

```
public class list {
    List<Entry> People = new ArrayList<>(); 
        BufferedReader br = null;
    String csvFile = "employee_data.csv";
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    public void readFromFile(){ 
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] Labels = line.split(cvsSplitBy);                 
                Entry entry = new Entry(Labels[0], Labels[1], Labels[2], Labels[3], Labels[4], Labels[5], Labels[6], Labels[7]);
                People.add(entry);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then this is the main, where I want the populated list to print its size:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(People.size());
}
```

If I read it in through the main method, it works fine. But when I try to move it to its own class, the list, People, cannot be resolved. Why is that?

Comment: Can you show the code in which you move it to its own class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `People` is now an instance member of the class `list`. In order to access it, you would need to first create an instance of `list`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    list myList = new list();
    myList.readFromFile();
    System.out.print(myList.People.size());
}
```

That being said, there are a variety of things I would consider reworking in the code. Class names should start with a capital letter, class variables should start with a lower case letter. Consider accessing `People` via a getter method on `list`, i.e.

```
public class list {
    ...

    public List<Entry> getPeople() {
        return People;
    }
}
```

Refer to [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) for specifics on lots of these types of tips.